# Only returning a singular character

Tags: c#

Whenever I run this code, it returns one character. I've tried various things, and at most it returns 5 or so lines, each containing one character. I'm trying to find each folder in the "Users" folder, and make my code list them, any help would be appreciated.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApp3
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //Search for directories and foreach, try to start discord
            try
            {
                var Bruhm = new List<string>();
                Bruhm.Add(Directory.GetDirectories(@"C:\Users\").ToString());
                int y = 0;
                foreach (string x in Bruhm) { 
                    Console.WriteLine(x[y]);
                   y = y+1;

                }
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e);
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(-1);
            }
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(-1);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first mistake you are making is;

```
Bruhm.Add(Directory.GetDirectories(@"C:\Users\").ToString());
```

will add only one string, which is `System.String[]` to your list.

The second mistake is, `x[y]` will print only one character, which is the character at y index inside the string x.

Change the Add() to AddRange(), and do not call ToString() on your list.

Try this:

```
var Bruhm = new List<string>();
Bruhm.AddRange(Directory.GetDirectories(@"C:\Users\"));
foreach (string x in Bruhm)
{
    Console.WriteLine(x);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are converting a list into a string and printing an index of it and it makes wrong result. You can extract the folder name using this code. "C:\Users\" has removed from the folder's path to provide folders' name not path.

```
var path = @"C:\Users\";
var Bruhm = Directory.GetDirectories(path).Select(x => x.Substring(path.Length));
foreach (string x in Bruhm)
{
    Console.WriteLine(x);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's quite simple. You're doing error with this: Directory.GetDirectories(@"C:\Users\").ToString()

Instead try this:

```
var Bruhm = Directory.GetDirectories(@"C:\Users\");
foreach(var subdir in Bruhm)
    Console.WriteLine(subDir);
```